# how to reset angular form and set default values after submitting

Tags: angular, angular-forms

My expected results is to reset the form after it has been submit and set its default values binded to the formGroup control. I am attempt to reset the form to its default data after submitting by calling reset() on the form submit. Please advise me on how can I reset the default value in the date and time field .

Example :

```
pickupDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);
pickupTime = moment().format() ;

onSubmit(orderData: Order){
        this.apiService(orderData).subscribe( order => {
                 orderForm.reset()
})
}
```

Please help 
Thanks

Comment: You have to set the model properties to empty strings. Clearing the form won't do what you expect.

Comment: You can patchValues to the form or re-build the form after resetting.

Comment: @RandyCasburn resetting the form fields to empty string would not be efficient  to add to it my form group has a allot of fields.

Comment: @AnuradhaGunasekara can you be more clear on how I can achieve this using patchValue.

Comment: my formgroup looks similar to this:
this.orderForm = fb.group({
  pickupDate: [this.pickupDate, Validators.required],
  pickupTime: [this.pickupTime, Validators.required]
})

Comment: @d-shall I'll add an answer.. Check it

Answer (score 11):

After submitting your form. you are calling

`this.yourForm.reset()`

Then you can patch initial values to the form like this.

```
this.yourForm.patchValue({
  firstControllerName: this.initialValues.value1,
  secondControllerName: this.initialValues.value2,
  // other controller names goes here
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I reinitialize the form after calling reset

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how your formBuilder looks like, but

this.yourForm.reset({}) already does the trick to empty fields that weren't predetermined. You could attempt something similar to this...

```
  ngOnChanges() {
    this.queryForm.reset({
    });

    // We generate an empty form again. 
    this.createForm();
  }
```

And your createForm could look like this...

```
createForm() {

    // As the method name suggests, we create a form. A form consists of Groups, Controls - and optionally - Arrays...
    this.queryForm = new FormGroup({
      query: new FormControl(''),

      formArray: new FormArray([this.initQueryConditions())
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can reset and set the default values you want at the same time like this:

```ts
    defaultFormValues: any = {
        date: Date.now
    };

    formG: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
        'date': new FormControl(this.defaultFormValues.date)
    });

    onSubmit(orderData: Order) {
        this.apiService(orderData).subscribe(order => {
            this.formG.reset(this.defaultFormValues);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Approach for clearing depends whether you are using Template driven forms or Reactive forms.

[Angular Forms, check full syntax with explaination](https://angular.io/guide/forms)

If template, then you need to set the model object to a default one (not necessarily empty).
If reactive, then call a method which explictly empties each of form's value.

After that, do the form.Reset to move it back to "pristine | unchanged" state, thus removing validators as well

Answer (score 0):

What I have found convenient is to **segregate the form creation** into a separate function. This way you can always reset the whole form just by calling the function.

```
  public form: FormGroup;
  private createForm(): void {
    this.form = this.builder.group({
      title: [ '', [Validators.required] ],
      description: [ '', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(200)] ],
      category: [ '', [Validators.required] ]
    });
  }

  private onSubmit(data) {
    this.apiService(data).subscribe(order => {
      this.createForm();
    });
  }
```